# The absolute child element disappear when going beyond its parent container

Tags: css, materialize

In my example, the child element is the `indicators`. Its position is set to `absolute` and bottom to `0`.
Its parent container is set to position `relative`.
So I expect it to be pushed out of the parent container when I set its bottom to like `-40px`. But it just disappears when it goes beyond the parent container.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider" style="width:30%;margin:auto" >
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://comotion.uw.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://comotion.uw.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://comotion.uw.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.carousel .indicators {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: -30px; //it cannot go over -40px otherwise disapper
 }
```

Other codes not that relevant are linked in the example, not showing them all here otherwise the post will get bloaded.

[I am the example](https://codepen.io/frostless/pen/aKQEXO)

Comment: Please put the relevant code directly into your question. You can keep the link to support your question, but your question cannot rely on it. Your question will be closed otherwise

Comment: Please don't ignore the rules of SO, links to codepen must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.carousel` has an `overflow: hidden;` thats why they disappear.